# converting svg data to image using imagick php

Tags: php, imagick

```
 $image->readImageBlob($svg);
 $image->setImageFormat("png24");
 $image->resizeImage(700,450, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1); 
 $image->writeImage($fileName);
```

I am converting svg data to image, it's working fine on localhost and on staging server but image text becomes blur on live server. I have checked and both servers have the same Imagick version and php extension.
[staging server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FBw9.png)

[live server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RLHd.png)

Comment: can you provide the images resulting from the local and the live env? You can change the content if its sensitive, only need a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I suspect you have different fonts available on the server. Also check if ImageMagick is using the same FreeType and GhostScript versions (which can be different even when ImageMagick is ostensibly the same version). Did you build ImageMagick from source or use a pre-built binary? What OS are you using locally vs. in the server?

Comment: I use a pre-built binary .On live aws server on staging linux base server

Answer (score 0):

Use png32

```
$image->setImageFormat("png32")
```

Comment: please add more explanation for others to understand your answer better